# What regex expression would I need in order to extract S{}fAct from input?

Tags: regex

**Input string:**

> S{WCS-STD}bUsr | S{logan}bUid | S{%24contact_person_id%24}sCmd |
> S{}sId | A{}sNme | S{}sUrl | S{}sLbl | S{}sCok | S{}mMsg | S{test}fAct
> | S{}fTyp | S{}fKey | S{}fVal | S{}bUserType | S{CUST}transType |
> S{}mTsp | S{2017-12-19 18:54:49}mDeptId | S{999}bPvtMsg | S{0}bToPvt |
> S{null}mOffRecord | S{null}entityName | S{null}}|

**String to identify:**

S{test}fAct (the value between the brackets is alphanumeric)

**Question**
How can I extract the string listed above with a Regex expression? I am a novice with regex and need help creating the correct expression.

I have tried the following but am unable to only select the S{}fAct attribute:

```
\| S{.+}fAct \|
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/uefLBA/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
^.+(S\{(.+[a-zA-Z0-9])\}fAct).+$
```

Explanation:

- ^ - Start of string
- .+ - One or more characters before S{test}fAct
- .+[a-zA-Z0-9] - One or more alphanumeric
- .+ - One or more characters after S{test}fAct
- $ end of string

Regex tester
https://regex101.com/r/m8068B/1

Comment: You are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

For the cleanest solution, I recommend @Sach's answer.  However, if you don't want to deal with capturing groups, here's an alternate solution which only matches the `S{test}fAct` portion:

```
.+(?=S{.+}fAct)\KS{.+}fAct
```

Explanation:

- `.+` Matches as many characters as it can
- `(?=S{.+}fAct)` A positive lookahead - constrains the match so that it has to stop before your desired string
- `\K` Consumes all characters matched so far so they will not be included in the final match
- `S{.+}fAct` Now we can just match the desired string, since we already consumed everything that wasn't part of it.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/THJ1cu/1

Please note that this is far from the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can match `|` , then capture the value you want in a capturing group and assert what is on the right side is again  `|`

Using a positive lookahead allows matching the same pattern in case it occurs right after it and you want both to match.

```
\| (S{[A-Za-z0-9]+}fAct)(?= \|)
```

**Explanation**

- `\|`  Match a pipe and space
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `S{[A-Za-z0-9]+}` Match `S{`, then 1+ alphanumberic chars followed by `}` The `+` prevents an empty `{}`, if that is allowed use an `*` instead.
- `fAct` Match literally
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?= \|)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is a space and pipe

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fo5NgD/1)